# Combining Data in Two Tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm sure a very basic question, but I'm continue to be stuck:

```
Table A - image_number, camera_type, total_sales
Table B - image_number, keyword
```

Table A has one ROW for each `image_number` - example:

```
image_number="AXJ789, camera_type="Nikon", total_sales=678
image_number="JIJ123", camera_type="Canon", total_sales=999
image_number="KNI908", camera_type="Sony", total_sales=565
```

Table B has many ROWs for each `image_number` - example:

```
image_number="AXJ789", keyword = "rain"
image_number="AXJ789", keyword = "mountain"
image_number="AXJ789", keyword = "grass"
image_number="AXJ789", keyword = "cloud"
```

What I'm trying to do is JOIN the two tables so that I can generate the following output:

> image_number="AXJ789", camera_type=678, camera_type="Nikon", keyword(1) =    "rain", keyword(2) = "mountain", keyword(3) = "grass", keyword(4) = "cloud"

In other words, I want to have all items in each ROW in table A + all the items from table B.  For each `image_number` in Table A, there could be no "keywords" in Table B or 50 keywords - depends on the image.

When I do an INNER JOIN, of course I can get one "keyword" from table B, but I can't figure out how to get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a comma-separated list of keywords for each image using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and `JOIN` (but use a `LEFT JOIN` if an image may have no keywords).

```
SELECT a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(b.keyword) AS keyword_list
FROM a
JOIN b on b.image_number = a.image_number
GROUP BY a.image_number
```

Output for your sample data:

```
image_number    camera_type     total_sales     keyword_list
AXJ789          Nikon           678             rain,mountain,grass,cloud
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7c0c8bf264dcfcb2f9cd735902631111)

You can then parse this into an array in your application, for example in PHP (if you have read the row into `$row`):

```
$keywords = explode(',', $row['keyword_list']);
print_r($keywords);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => rain
    [1] => mountain
    [2] => grass
    [3] => cloud
)
```

Comment: Yeah.  Concat.  Makes sense.  I woke up last night realizing that I could dump to excel and then concat and then dump back in to Table A.   This is super clear.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the keywords together:

```
select a.*,
       (select group_concat(b.keyword)
        from b
        where b.image_number = a. image_number
       ) as keywords
from a;
```

This creates a comma-delimited list of the keywords.  This is much simpler (in MySQL) than trying to put them in separate columns.  In fact, if you wanted separate columns, I might suggest parsing this result:

```
select a.*,  -- or whatever columns you want
       substring_index(keywords, ',' 1) as keyword1,
       substring_index(substring_index(keywords, ',' 2), ',', -1) as keyword2,
       substring_index(substring_index(keywords, ',' 3), ',', -1) as keyword3,
       substring_index(substring_index(keywords, ',' 4), ',', -1) as keyword4
from a left join 
     (select b.image_number, group_concat(b.keyword) as keywords
      from b
      group by b.image_number
     ) b
     on b.image_number = a. image_number;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Will give it a spin.